# paymentType in CallShortcutExpressCheckout for donations

Tags: api, paypal, express-checkout

what paymentType must be set for donations in Classic API CallShortcutExpressCheckout function?

In docs it seems can be only Sale or Order or Authorization

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Payment action and flow type are orthogonal. Sale/Order/Authorization control how the money moves, not describe why the money is moving (donation versus commerce).

So you can use any of sale/order/authorization when collecting donations. A simple sale transaction (ie instantly moving the money, not waiting for any later action before settling) is the simplest and is probably the best idea in most donation circumstances.

Comment: Thank you geewiz!

Paypal has contacted my client asking to choose "donation" to move money from paypal to association bank account but I'm a bit confused of  what I have to change in my code.

Comment: The donation flow is for a business (or individual) to collect donations from other people. It works exactly the same as express checkout would work if that business were selling goods or services except there are no goods or services being rendered to the payers. The funds are credited to the business's PayPal account, not a bank account. Funds can separately be withdrawn from a PayPal account to a bank account but that is not related to the donations or express checkout flows so... I'm not sure what you are being asked to do or what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok! Thank you! I'll check what my clients want to do :D